# Subprocess.call appears to modify (rsync) command inputs causing failure

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

I am attempting to write a python script that calls rsync to synchronize code between my vm and my local machine. I had done this successfully using subprocess.call to write from my local machine to my vm, but when I tried to write a command that would sync from my vm to my local machine, subprocess.call seems to erroneously duplicate text or modify the command in a way that doesn't make sense to me.

I've seen a number of posts about subprocess relating to whether a shell is expected / being used, but I tried running the command with both `shell=True` and shell=False` and saw the same weird command modification.

Here is what I am running:

```py
command = ['rsync', '-avP', f'{user}@{host}:/home/{user}/Workspace/{remote_dir}', os.getcwd()])  # attempting to sync from a dir on my remote machine to my current directory on my local machine
print('command: ' + ' '.join(command))
subprocess.call(command)
```

Here is the output (censored):

```
command: rsync -avP  benjieg@[hostname]:/home/benjieg/Workspace/maige[dirname] /Users/benjieg/Workspace
building file list ...
rsync: link_stat "/Users/benjieg/Workspace/benjieg@[hostname]:/home/benjieg/Workspace/[dirname]" failed: No such file or directory (2)
8383 files to consider

sent 181429 bytes  received 20 bytes  362898.00 bytes/sec
total size is 217164673  speedup is 1196.84
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/810eba08-405a-11ed-86e9-6af958a02716/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

If I run the command directly in my terminal, it works just fine. The mysterious thing that i'm seeing is that subprocess appears to append some extra path before my user name in the command. You can see this in the 'link stat' line in the output. I'm guessing this is why it's unable to find the directory. But I really can't figure out why it would do that.

Further, I tried moving out of the 'Workspace' directory on my local machine to home, and even more weird behavior ensued. It seemed to begin looking into all of the files on my local machine, even prompting dropbox to ask me if iterm2 had permission to access it. Why would this happen? Why would whatever subprocess is doing cause a search of my whole local file system? I'm really mystified by this seemingly random behavior.

I'm on MacOS 13.0.1 (22A400) using python 3.10.4

Comment: Try adding `'echo'` at the beginning of your `command` list to see exactly what it's doing.  I seriously doubt `subprocess` is changing anything; it's almost like your `rsync` version doesn't recognize the ssh addressing.  Does it work if you add `'-e','ssh'`?

Comment: i'm using rsync version 2.6.9 with protocol version 29 fwiw. Adding echo before just prints the command, which looks correct to me. would I add those things at the beginning or the end?

Comment: It's the same order you'd use in a command line -- put it just after the `-avP`.

Comment: I tried that but I didn't see any difference in behavior